Blazor : Access to server's razor page from the client
I'm new in blazor web app development.
I would like to access to a component.razor page locate in the server-side from the client-side.
In the server the page is located in "ServerProject/Components/Pages/Testpage.razor. The page link declared is @page "/testpage".

        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="testpage" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="bi bi-house-door-fill-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Test
            </NavLink>
        </div>

I used the page declaration in the NavMenu.razor located on the client side to access to the page. When I click on the navbar link, the page load but soon after it return "Not found".
What do I have to do to make it worked?
May be the question is so simple for some of you that if someone has a correct answer he/she will rush to write it. I do not know a lot so, please be as specific as you can.

change href="testpage"  to href="/testpage"  and see if that works

@MayurEkbote Save issue. Ref the link git demo
